# Is creating folders in s3 bucket is recommended? What are pros and cons of this design?

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, object-storage

I am looking for the recommendation, we want to use aws s3 buckets for storage of big unstructured data. Since s3 only allows 100 buckets per account, so I am not very sure about this.

Comment: An S3 bucket can contain an unlimited number and size of objects. It's quite normal to partition files by their key, emulating a folder structure. Also note that you can request an increase to the number of S3 buckets, if absolutely needed.

Comment: OK, that make sense. But then how do we do security at folder level? Do S3 takes care of that? If yes, by what means? I understand that. they do encryption and decryption of data, but that's not suffice. We are service provider, where multiple tenants would be using the same bucket. How folder within aws bucket can be isolated with security? For one bucket there will be single access-key, but what about folder in a bucket?